# Keras add_loss will not work with y data(y_train, y_test) on Encoder-Decoder model

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I found some weird activity by using add_loss function in Keras model compare to use loss='something like mse' in compile function while I was coding exercises for auto-encoder.

The same model of that uses loss in compile function requires y_train and y_test(if I use validation_data) as usual, but add_loss(mse(inputs,outputs)) emits the error if I provide y data(y_train/ y_test).

Here is the simple code I have made to train mnist, flattened to be 784 dim from 28 x 28.

the common body of the sample code is as below:

```
encode_dim = 32
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(encode_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

encoder = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=encoded)
print(encoder.summary())

encoded_inputs = Input(shape=(encode_dim, ))

decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded_inputs)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

decoder = Model(inputs=encoded_inputs, outputs=decoded)
print(decoder.summary())

outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs))
ae = Model(inputs, outputs)
print(ae.summary())
```

1. with providing loss by name in compile function would be like below:

   ```
   ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
   ae.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=256)
   ```

would work, 
2. but with the case below:

```
ae_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
ae.add_loss(ae_loss )    
ae.compile(optimizer='adam')
ae.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=256)
```

will give the error like below:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 deep_vaestyle_model2 = AutoEncoderTester(DeepModelVAEStyle())
>         2 deep_vaestyle_model2.train(x_train=x_train_flat, y_train=x_train_flat, x_test=x_test_flat, y_test=x_test_flat,
>   ----> 3                 epochs=1, batch_size=1024, verbose=1)
>         4 deep_vaestyle_model2.test(x_test=x_test_flat)
>
> in train(self, x_train, y_train,
>   x_test, y_test, epochs, batch_size, verbose)
>        16                                                   histogram_freq=0,
>        17                                                   write_graph=True,
>   ---> 18                                                   write_grads=True,
>        19 #                                                   batch_size=batch_size,
>        20 #                                                   write_images=True
>
> d:\igs_projects\realtime_eeg_analyzer\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   **kwargs)
>       950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
>       951             class_weight=class_weight,
>   --> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
>       953         # Prepare validation data.
>       954         do_validation = False
>
> d:\igs_projects\realtime_eeg_analyzer\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   check_array_lengths, batch_size)
>       787                 feed_output_shapes,
>       788                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
>   --> 789                 exception_prefix='target')
>       790 
>       791             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and
>
> d:\igs_projects\realtime_eeg_analyzer\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py
>   in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
>   exception_prefix)
>        61             raise ValueError('Error when checking model ' +
>        62                              exception_prefix + ': '
>   ---> 63                              'expected no data, but got:', data)
>        64         return []
>        65     if data is None:
>
> ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but
>   got:', array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>          ...,
>          [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]))

but if I give y data(y_train, and y_test) as None, then it runs as I expected.

I tried to find out why keras consider those two are different but I couldn't. Can someone explain????

Comment: `mse` is not a function. You can't just call it like that.

Comment: You can calculate the loss as `ae_loss` and pass it to your `add_loss`

Comment: I don't know whether mse is a function or not, but I am 100% sure I can use it like the code above. In fact I found the code from official keras github for variational autoencoder. They added loss function like that

Comment: Can you post the link to what you are referring?

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py
from line 176 to 188

Comment: Okay. I don't exactly know why 2 is failing; but I am sure you can use a custom loss as in 1 and it would still work the same way. I need to figure out how `add_loss` is actually handled internally.

Comment: @Anakin I think I found out why. ae_loss = mse(inputs, outputs) should be ae_loss = mse(output_feed, outputs). In my case, loss inputs itself is defined to compare with inputs and outputs, which is prediction, not with outputs_true.